# Terraform Planning to delete resources when planning changes

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I currently have a terraform directory that looks like this:

```
└── aws
    ├── iam
    │   └── iam.tf
    ├── services
    │   └── services.tf
    └── vpc.tf
```

The backend is S3 and we're using workspaces. I'm using the same workspace and backend config for each tf configuration.

Steps that I'm performing:

1. `terraform init` in the /aws directory.
2. Select workspace
3. `terraform apply`
4. `vpc.tf` resources are successfully created.
5. cd ~/aws/services
6. `terraform init` and select same workspace

When I do a `terraform plan` for `~/aws/services/services.tf`, the plan shows that the `services.tf` resources will be created, but that it's going to delete all the resources previously created by `vpc.tf` as well.

The same occurs if I go to `~/aws/iam` and try to `terraform plan` for `iam.tf` as well. The plan shows the resources will be created, but that the VPC resources will be removed.

There are no resources or changes created that would require VPC resources to be deleted/recreated/changed.

Should I not use the same workspace/backend key for these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When terraform runs, it creates it's dependency graph from all *.tf files in the current directory only.  So when you run `terraform apply` in your `aws/iam` directory, terraform does not see your vpc.tf file.  However, when terraform checks the s3 backend state file, it sees the vpc resources; since these resources are not in the dependency graph, it marks them for destruction.  Because of this behavior, it's common practice to use a different backend state file for each separate directory.  This separates components out by "stacks" or layers of your infrastructure.

A simple layout of backend keys would be to have a state file for each directory.  i.e. have the distinct s3 backend keys of `aws/iam/terraform.tfstate`, `aws/services/terraform.tfstate`, and `aws/vpc/terraform.tfstate`.  Or something of that effect.  This setup, would allow what you are intending; to be able to create, modify, and/or delete service resources without affecting vpc resources.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This is the approach I'm following now.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think the issue was that I was referring to the same state file in each of my *.tf files. Creating different files for each *.tf seems to have resolved the issue.

If that's not best practice or if there's a way to write to one state file, please let me know.